# Why is gauche conformer of 2,3 dimethyl butane more stable than its anti conformer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, conformers

Why is gauche conformer of **2,3-dimethylbutane** seen along 2,3 bond more stable than its anti conformer? It seems to be anomalous to me as in most other butane like compunds anti form is more stable than gauche form.Can someone explain me the reason why the compound shows [Gauche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauche_effect)?

Also does this anomaly hold in case of **2,3-diphenylbutane** and **2,3-dimethylpentane**?

Comment: Related: [Conformations of butane](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/11015/7951) and [How can the gauche-effect be explained?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39102/7951)

Comment: @Loong I saw those links.They do not explain the case of 2,3-dimethylbutane.

Comment: I am also confused by this and asked a more general question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/56979/confusion-about-gauche-effect). When it's answered, if it doesn't also answer yours, I'll be happy to come back here.

Comment: @S.Chevalier Your question is different from mine.Your one is answered in Wikipedia page I linked named Gauche Effect in my question above.

Comment: Could it be possible that the conformation where the *hydrogens* are *anti* is called ***gauche***?

Comment: No.Even the hydrogens are in gauche position.And I found out the reason for stability  today.Will answer the question soon.